# Python file read rewind

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, python-import

Reading a file in using Python. The file format is like this:

```
[22/Oct/2013] GET KEYWORD apple/banana/tomato
ID=23q539283492u39
ERROR:2
ERROR:3
parameters={}
...
```

I am only interested in all ERROR:3, so once an ERROR:3 is spotted, the first line (time and keywords) needs to be extracted. But it seems the reading head has passed the first line when the error codes are read. How do I rewind the reading position? Can I used something simple? Or it has to be compicated?

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
for line in f:  
  #when ERROR:3, print line1 with the timpstamp and keywords
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the keystamp info while you read ahead... Print it if you hit an error, replace it when you get to the next stamp...

Comment: Yes, it's always easier to just remember stuff than to go back and get it.